# Insert a tikz figure to the top left in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am using the following [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/the-honk-kong-polytechnic-university-polyu-beamer-presentation-theme/vywngqprjwrq) from Overleaf. I tried to remove the logo from the top left area by changing

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hspace{0.06\textwidth}\pgfuseimage{\@SINTEFlogo}}
```

to

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
```

But after that, the titles in all pages disappear.

- What is the correct way to remove that logo please?
- What should I do if I want to draw a logo at the same place using tikz for every slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme you use uses a big negative space at the start of the frametitle to move it besides the logo. If you switch off the logo, you also have to remove this space, otherwise the frametitle goes outside of the visible area:

```
\documentclass{sintefbeamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vspace*{2ex}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[
%  leftskip=2cm
  ]{frametitle}%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\
    \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just want to replace the image with a tikz picture, you can alter the original definition of the headline:

```
\documentclass{sintefbeamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\hspace{0.06\textwidth}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue] (0,0) circle [radius=1cm];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from this code:

```
% Put the logo in each slide's top left area
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

% Define frame title and subtitle layout
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \vspace*{2ex}\tikz[overlay]{
  \fill [yellow] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (2,0) -- cycle;
  \fill [red!40] (0.5,0.5) -- (1,0) -- (1.5,0.5) -- cycle;
  }% must have this % to avoid space between figure and title
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=2cm]{frametitle}%
    \usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\\
    \usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

[image]